# Cannot assign a value of type UIImage? to a value of type Dynamic<UIImage?>

Tags: xcode, swift, parsing

I am trying to call my image but it is showing this error : 
" Cannot assign a value of type  UIImage?  to a value of type Dynamic " exactly in this line "post.image1 = UIImage(data: data!, scale:1.0)
" .

```
let postsQuery = Post.query()       
        postsQuery!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(result: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            self.posts = result as? [Post] ?? []
            for post in self.posts {
                // 2
                let data = post.imageFile?.getData()
                // 3
                post.image1 = UIImage(data: data!, scale:1.0)
            }
            // 9
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Optional chaining, UIImage constructor,  here will always return an optional result. You need to safely unwrap it using if..let  optional binding.

Answer (score 1):

You have to unwrap like as :

```
if let image = UIImage(data:yourImageData) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
         self.yourImageView.image = image
    }
}
```

Comment: i have to unwrap the image  where exactly !? because i am calling it from post class ! and can you explain  why you're doing asynchronous while  unwraping " dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())" please . Thank you so much !

Comment: @Yahyacode If image is big then it take time to load. by the using of asynchronous dispatch you can perform your task until image is added to imageview or the object. else your screen/process will hang up.

Comment: Swift 3 : replace "dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())"
with "DispatchQueue.main.async"

Comment: @CornellSkyers Thank you, but you can also edit the answer. :)